# How to escape new line chars in php to output into a javascript string value?

Tags: php, javascript

I pulling out some html/text strings that I need to insert into a javascript variable.

eg, that's how it would look in php:

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n";
echo "var myvar='{$value}'";
echo "\n</script>";
```

The problem with the above approach is that some special characters would actually break the javascript code.

So, I tried using htmlspecialchars:

```
htmlspecialchars($value,11,'utf-8',true); //11 stands for ENT_QUOTES|ENT_SUBSTITUTE
```

This did replace some unusual chars and most importantly the quotes.

However the new line chars pass it by and break my javascript.

So how could I escape the new line chars? I need to preserve them to be used later in the textareas.

****EDIT**** I will post a sample value of my variable. (They are actually the input from Tiny_mce)

```
 <p>You've been...</p>
 <p><iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/8d7OBluielc?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" width="640" height="360"></iframe></p>
```

Comment: AJAX + JSON would be a "sane" solution.

Comment: Why are you talking about ajax?

Comment: @elclanrs Sorry but I don't understand. care to explain ?

Comment: @Anonymous if you show us an example for the content of `$value` it would help.

Comment: @alfasin Well, It contains html/text, ok let me post one.

Comment: Instead of `"\n"`, try `PHP_EOL`.

Comment: @AymanSafadi performing twice `str_replace` ? oiy vay... :P

Comment: **@Anonymous** & **@alfasin** take a look at **deceze** answer, that's what I meant by "sane". And AJAX, well it's just easier to manage than `echo`ing strings all over the place...

Comment: @elclanrs well Json does make sense to me, I have no problem with that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myvar = <?php echo json_encode($value); ?>;
</script>
```

JSON == Javascript notation == the proper encoding/escaping method for any values output to Javascript.

Comment: I have a question though, would it handle UTF-8 characters?

Comment: In fact: [This function only works with UTF-8 encoded data.](http://php.net/json_encode)